# Kirchoffs Law for 3 Loop Circuit with Multiple Voltage Supplies

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, network

[image][image: Circuit With Currents Labelled]I am working on the below circuit to find; the power dissipated by RL (8Ω resistor), voltage drop across RL and current supplied by the 10 volt battery (V1).

So far I have used Kirchoff's law to the best of my ability to get 3 loop equations but 4 unknowns, I am thrown off by the variable voltage supply V3 = 3Is

In my workings I have used I1=Is for simplicity.

Loop 1

$$0=10-6I_1-20I_2 $$

Loop 2

$$0=35I_2-11I_1-6I_3 - 5V$$

Loop 3

$$0=4I_1-14I_3-18I_4$$ $$V3=4I_1$$

(I can share my workings if required).

Please could you help with confirming my loop equations are correct and helping to derive a 4th equation so that I can solve the currents I1-I4. (I can post my workings if needed).

My assignment is a simulation assignment, but I can't build a model with out having my hand calcs correct.

Comment: I am working on the below circuit????? Where???

Comment: Edit: Should show now. 

Does the circuit not show? It's there for me.

Comment: I see NO circuit.

Comment: The image URL is https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cHYD.png I am not sure why it's not showing for me. I have tried uploading the image and providing own URL.

Comment: Ah... it's showing now. You must have fixed the link when you edited it. Now please indictae I1, I2 and I3 etc. on the diagram.

Comment: How can you have I1 in all loops? For example why 11I1 in loop 2?

Comment: @Andyaka I've added in how I labelled the currents.

Comment: @G36 In loop 3 $$V3 = 4I_1$$ So i've substituted in. 

For loop 2 current at $$R_3=15(I_1-I_2)$$ I've then multiplied out and simplified. That's branch rule right?

Comment: You have three loops but four currents (I1..I4). Seems you are using a mix of Kirchofs voltage law with Kirchofs current law. Draw three **loop** currents. Then when work through each loop adding the voltages.

Comment: The current through R5 is I1-I2-I3, not I4. The current through RL is the same (they are in series).

Answer (score 1):

Applying KCL on Node \$V_2\$ 
\$I_1 - I_2 = I_4 + I_3 \$
=> \$I_4 = I_1 - I_2 - I_3\$ 
The 4th variable depends on the other 3.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the equations should look like this:

Loop 1
$$10V - 6\Omega I_1 - 20\Omega I_2 = 0$$ 
Loop 2
$$20\Omega I_2 - 15\Omega(I_1 - I_2) + 5V - 6\Omega I_3 - 4\Omega I_1 = 0$$
Loop 3 
$$4\Omega I_1 + 6\Omega I_3 - (10\Omega + 8\Omega)((I1-I2) - I3) = 0$$

And the situation is

$$I_1 =\frac{165}{229} \approx 0.72052A$$
$$ I_2 = \frac{65}{229} \approx 0.28384A$$
$$I_3 = \frac{95}{458} \approx 0.20742A$$

Comment: @OwenMorris Error where? Your simulations show VR2 = 5.68V hence the I2 current is 5.68V/20Ω = 0.284A

Comment: removed my comment. All works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> So far I have used Kirchoff's law to the best of my ability to get 3
>   loop equations but 4 unknowns,

It *sounds* like your approach is [mesh analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_analysis) but if so, you're not applying it correctly.

For three loops (without current sources), mesh analysis requires that you solve the circuit in terms of three *mesh currents*.  Note that a mesh current isn't necessarily the current through a resistor or other circuit element.

In this case, the mesh currents \$I_A, I_B, I_C\$ circulate, say, clockwise in the first, second, and third loops respectively.

It is then clear that \$I_S = I_A\$ and that \$I_{R_L} = I_C\$

But the current through \$R_2\$ is \$I_A - I_B\$ while the current through \$R_4\$ is \$I_B - I_C\$.

If you write your KVL equations using the mesh currents, you should come up with three independent equations in three unknowns.